# actionscript3.0 replace curly brace pair

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, curly-braces

```
var strToBeReplace:String= "Hi! I am {0}, and I like {1}, I used to be a {2}"; // many {\d} like curly brace to be replace
trace(replaceCurlyBrace(strToBeReplace, "tom", "eating", "techer"));
// expect output: Hi! I am tom, and I like eating, I used to be a teacher

function replaceCurlyBrace(str:String, ... args):void
{
     // ... how to implement

}
```

I had tried this:

```
var str:String = "bla bla {0} bla";
var reg:Regexp = new Regexp("{0}");
trace(strToBeReplace.replace(reg,"tim"));
// real output : bla bla {0} bla
```

but it did't work.

I had tried double slash style regexp : /{0}/, but ide complains syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by what you have tried :

```
var reg:RegExp = new RegExp('{0}');     // you can write it : var reg:RegExp = /{0}/;
var str:String = 'bla bla {0} bla';

trace(str.replace(reg, 'tim'));
```

Here you should know that `{}` is a [quantifier metacharacter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eab.html) 
which is used to specify a numeric quantifier or quantifier range for a previous item, so for example, if you write `/a{3}/` you tell 
the compiler that you are looking for any 'aaa' string, so in reality writing `/{0}/` doesn't have any sens or utility.

So to indicate to the compiler that you are looking for the string `"{0}"`, you can do like this :

```
var reg:RegExp = /{[0]}/;   // you can write it : var reg:RegExp = new RegExp('{[0]}');
```

OR, you can escape the `{}` using a single `\` ( `\\` if using a string ) :

```
var reg:RegExp = /\{0}/;    // you can write it : var reg:RegExp = new RegExp('\\{0}');
```

Which give you this code :

```
var reg:RegExp = new RegExp('\\{0}');
var str:String = 'bla bla {0} bla';

trace(str.replace(reg, 'tim'));     // gives : bla bla tim bla
```

Returning to your question, you have `n` words to replace within your string, so you can do like this :

```
var str:String = 'Welcome to {0}, the free {1} that {2} can {3}.';
    str = replaceCurlyBrace(str, 'Wikipedia', 'encyclopedia', 'anyone', 'edit');

trace(str); // gives : Welcome to Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia that anyone can edit.

function replaceCurlyBrace(str:String, ... args): String {

    var exp0:RegExp = /\{/,     //  or : /{[/
        exp1:RegExp = /}/,      //  or : /]}/
        regex:RegExp;

    // if we have words
    if(args.length > 0) {   
        for(var i:int = 0; i<args.length; i++){
            // you can also write it : regex = new RegExp('\\{' + i + '}');
            // or                      regex = new RegExp('{[' + i + ']}');
            regex = new RegExp(exp0.source + i + exp1.source);  
            str = str.replace(regex, args[i]);
        }       
    }   
    return str;

}
```

For more details about [`RegExp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html), you can take a look on :

- [Regular expression syntax](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea9.html).
- [Methods for using regular expressions with strings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea8.html).
- [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) ( or many other sites) where you can test your regular expressions.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression `\{\d*?\}`. Note that to escape characters, you need to use `\`, the backslash.
In your example 
    `var str:String = "bla bla {0} bla";
    var reg:Regexp = new Regexp("\{0\}");
    trace(strToBeReplace.replace(reg,"tim"));
    // real output : bla bla tim bla`